# Aren’t I? vs. Am I not?

Tags: word-order, questions, negation, contractions, tag-questions

1. I am a good man, aren’t I?
2. I am a good man, am I not?

The first sentence is often used. According to grammar books, the second sentence is also correct, but it is rarely used. Can native speakers please tell me when you use the second sentence?

Comment: You would only use the second if you were being consciously formal and old-fashioned.

Comment: If you use aren't I you would probably use: I'm a good man, with the contraction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am a good man, **aren’t I**?

is a normal usage. It's just looking for confirmation.

> I am a good man, **am I not**?

is more direct, asking for confirmation, especially in a case where it might not be believed.

Undoing a contraction often adds emphasis to a phrase.