# Aren't I or am I not

Tags: questions, tag-questions

The question tag for ***I am*** is ***aren't I?*** In interrogative sentences with ***I am***, should it be ***aren't I*** or ***am I not***? For example, which of the two is correct?

1. Am I not your friend?
2. Aren't I your friend?

Comment: I CV’d for lack of research, but a quick search shows that this is apparently a duplicate too: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/294712/aren-t-i-vs-am-i-not

Comment: No, it's not a duplicate. Please understand the difference between the two questions. Mine is related to interrogative sentences while the one you are referring to is related to question tags.

Answer (score 1):

Am I not your friend?
Aren't I your friend?

Both are correct. Both are interrogatives.

Tags with declarative sentences:
I am your friend, aren't I?
I am your friend, am I not? [more formal as mentioned in the other answer].

Negative interrogative:
I'm not your friend, am I?

Answer (score 0):

Formally, *am I not* is correct. In speech "aren't I" is much more common (in Australia at least). It can be argued that "aren't I" and "ain't I" are contractions of "am not I", as "amn't I" is difficult to pronounce. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ain%27t